# Tapping one notifiaction, removing all notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I am working on project where we are showing notifications for each photo album updates. But on tap of one notification, it is removing all notifications from the notification bar.

I tried the following code:

```
 private void handleNotification(NotificationModel notificationModel) {
    // display the notification in the notification bar
    int i=0;
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(notificationModel.getAlbum_id()))
        i=Integer.parseInt(notificationModel.getAlbum_id());

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.BUNDLE_ALBUM_ID_KEY, notificationModel.getAlbum_id());
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.BUNDLE_ALBUM_NAME_KEY, notificationModel.getAlbum_title());

    /*intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);*/
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),i,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    /*builder.setAutoCancel(true);*/
    // Large icon appears on the left of the notification
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    // Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
    builder.setContentTitle(notificationModel.getTitle());
    builder.setContentText(notificationModel.getMessage());
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification=builder.build();

    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
            | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(i,notification);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: or check value of i remain same each time that might be problem ...

Comment: @MohdSaquib tried that. but not working. checked the i value also. it is unique.

Comment: @Subhra Your code is absolutely working fine. Check same project in another device or check your device notification settings.

Comment: @Nikhil Tested in another device also. It's not working. And I could not find any settings for notification in the device settings related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check value of "i" that is working as notification id  remain same each time that might be problem ...
**Here**

```
int i=0;
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(notificationModel.getAlbum_id()))
        i=Integer.parseInt(notificationModel.getAlbum_id());
```

**Please check value of "i", I think its always same in your case that you are using with below code**

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),**i**,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And

```
notificationManager.notify(i,notification);
```

Comment: Checked the 'i' value. It is unique. If 'i' is same, separate notifications would not have been built for each album. Separate notifications are showing for each album.

Comment: Yes bro that is the main problem value of i should not be unique see i have given solution her try to understand logic value of notification id i.e. i in your code should be different each time.
When the value of i will different than you can achieve what u want.